# How to determine if my OS is a shared-memory multiprocessor platform

Tags: c, multithreading, multiprocessing, openmp

I'm writing a program written in C that needs to run many tasks in parallel. After doing research it seams the OpenMP API is a great fit. Further research shows there are cons to using OpenMP; specifically that it is restricted to shared-memory multiprocessor platforms.

**How can I determine if my OS + hardware is a shared-memory multiprocessor platform?**

I'd assume that most modern machines support multiprocessing.

Comment: You have it backwards: OpenMP _is_ the "multi-platform shared memory multiprocessing" framework on your system. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenMP

Comment: From a programmer standpoint; it's an API. So your answer does not tell me anything regarding whether or not it is supported by my hardware or OS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How can I determine if my OS + hardware is a shared-memory multiprocessor platform?

If it wasn't, you'd probably know so already.

Modern computers (including desktops, laptops, mobile devices, and most servers) are almost always shared-memory platforms, and as such can support OpenMP. Hardware that doesn't fall into this category is rare, and typically falls into one of two cases:

- Extremely large servers, cluster computers, and supercomputers.
- Esoteric and experimental architectures.

Comment: that's what I figured would be the case, thanks. I take it 'shared-memory' is nothing technical; it's defacto like I install more RAM and the OS automatically knows how to use it.

Comment: "Shared-memory" simply means that all of the processors in the system can access all of the memory in the system -- that is, the processors don't each have their own separate memory.

Comment: Exactly. It appears the author was being wordy and it threw me off. I appreciate the clarity.